# mounting local filesystems --- failed

Tags: linux, windows-xp, virtualbox, virtualization

When I start guest OS which is Oracle Linux 5 running on Virtual Box 4.2, I am getting

```
mounting local filesystems ---  failed
```

How can I resolve the issue?

Thanks

**etc/fstab**

```
/dev/VolGroup00/LogVol00 /                       ext3    defaults        1 1
LABEL=/boot             /boot                   ext3    defaults        1 2
tmpfs                   /dev/shm                tmpfs   default       0 0
devpts                  /dev/pts                devpts  gid=5,mode=620  0 0
sysfs                   /sys                    sysfs   defaults        0 0
proc                    /proc                   proc    defaults        0 0
/dev/VolGroup00/LogVol01 swap                    swap    defaults        0 0
```

*Update 2*

**Mount output**

```
/dev/mapper/VolGroup00-LogVol00 on / type ext3 (rw)
proc on /proc type proc (rw)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,gid=5,mode=620)
/dev/sda1 on /boot type ext3 (rw)
none on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type binfmt_misc (rw)
sunrpc on /var/lib/nfs/rpc_pipefs type rpc_pipefs (rw)
/dev/sr0 on /media/VBOXADDITIONS_4.2.4_81684 type iso9660 (ro,nosuid,nodev,uid=1101)
```

Comment: Tell everybody more.....like what is not being mounted, and a copy of your /etc/fstab.

Comment: @mdpc I have included etc/fstab in my question. Not sure which file system is not mounted. Thanks

Comment: Then show us the output of the `mount` command after you get this message.

Comment: @mdpc Included `mount` command output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resolved the issue, it was quite silly.

While editing /etc/fstab I accidentally missed s in default, it should be

```
tmpfs                   /dev/shm                tmpfs   defaults       0
```

it should not be

```
tmpfs                   /dev/shm                tmpfs   default       0
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Based on your output, the tmpfs is not being mounted.  You should investigate further, does your system have tmpfs?  Is /dev/shm a valid mount point?

Comment: I am a newbie, not sure how to check /dev/shm is a valid mount point or not? Thanks

Comment: Use the command /dev/shm....it should be a directory.

Comment: I have got the following `[oracledb@oel5 ~]$ /dev/shm
bash: /dev/shm: is a directory
[oracledb@oel5 ~]$`